# Can some illustrate the concept of language like Java or Groovy being considered as statically or dynamically typed or a dynamic language?

Tags: java, groovy

I am just trying to get my head around the concept of when is a programming language known to be statically or dynamically typed or considered as both either statically typed and dynamic language or dynamically typed and dynamic language at the same time.

What I am confused is that if a language is known to be statically typed when the type of variable is known or defined at compile time in the case of Java i.e.

```
//Java illustration of statically typed  
int x, y; //explicit type declaration 
x = 5, y = 10; //Now we use the variables 

//Groovy illustration of statically typed 
def x, y //explicit type declaration 
x = 1, y = 10 //now we use the variables
```

Based on reading various online sources, it says that the list of languages that are considered to be statically typed does not include Groovy, but Java and C++.

Also if Groovy is a dynamic language (definition of DL - DL is a language that does little or no checks at compile time, instead checks are done at run-time). Doesn't this mean that Groovy is also a dynamically typed language too, because for a variable to be considered to be dynamically typed "is when the type of variable is know at run-time instead of compile time".

```
//Illustration of a language being dynamically typed according to DT and DL definition
x = 5 //directly using the variable (exceptable in Python and PHP but not in Java/Groovy)
```

If that's the case in Groovy then above code illustration of Groovy being statically typed contradicts with Groovy definition of checks been done at runtime.

Does this mean that both java groovy are not dynamically typed languages, because directly using variable will throw compiler error in both Java and groovy.

Please correct me if am wrong. Please provide your examples with code illustration.

Comment: How is declaring `def x; x = 1` statically typed? No type information is provided.

Comment: @DaveNewton - def is a definition keyword, which means that that variable type could be anything (Object, String, int etc) at runtime, but at the end of the day its a type by default. Runtime will interpret variable type based on variable value if variable is given def type.

Comment: @Learner and the difference between "dynamic typing" and what you just said is...?

Comment: @Learner I'm not really sure what you just said--I'm asking how it isn't dynamic typing since the type held by `x` can change.

Comment: @DaveNewton - what I meant was that def by default is a type isn't it? If a var is given a type def and it is assigned any value. Then its type will be interpreted at runtime. Correct?

Comment: @Learner Aaaaand that's dynamic typing. But no, `def` isn't a type. It's any type. Anything. If the type of a value can change, it's dynamic.

Comment: @DaveNewton -  So is Groovy also statically typed or both statically or Dynamically typed?

Comment: @Learner It's dynamically typed. Groovy 2+ adds *optional* static type checking, so it's both, but the example you say is statically typed isn't. Needing `def` to disambiguate variable declarations doesn't make it statically typed.

Comment: 'def' is no more a type than 'for' is. 'def' is a keyword to indicate the name after it is a new variable just like 'for' is a keyword to indicate that some loop parameters follow with a statement (or block of them) following that.

Comment: Actually "def" is replacable by "Object".  In Java you could hold everything in an "Object" but the value held in that object always has a known type at runtime.  A variable of type "Object" is always know to be (at least) an "Object" at compile time, and possibly something more specific. These are true of both Java and Groovy, but Groovy tends to deal with things as "Objects" more often than Java.  Groovy also lets you attempt to call a method on an "Object" that it may not have, Java does not.  This is the main difference.

Comment: Also def i=7 is as fully typed as it is in java--the "i=7" part creates I as an int/Integer just as surely as if you'd typed "int i=7" and sticks it into and "Object".  It's just a syntatical shortcut, not a lack of type

Comment: @Learner, in groovy script `def` is not a mandatory prefix. you could use `x=5` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Static and dynamic typing are mainly descriptions of how **variables** (and function arguments and return values) are typed. In many statically typed languages, you'll have to declare the type of the variable so the compiler knows what operations are valid and which overloaded version of functions/operators should be used. A few modern statically-typed languages (including most functional languages) have type inference, so most of the time you do not have to declare the type of a variable. However, a variable must still have a **fixed** type. If you assign values of different types to the same variable, the compiler will either refuse to compile or it will only allow you to do the operation common to all. A truly strongly typed language cannot have type-related run time failures.

In a dynamically typed language, the variable is just a name. You can assign values of any type to any variable and the type can be changed by assigning a value of a different type. The validity of a function call or operation on a variable can only be checked at the time the statement is executed. (You can think of this as declaring every variable in Java as Object and cast them to a desired type when used. Of course, the compiler will not try to determine if the cast will succeed and will insert cast checks which may cause failure at run time.)

Dynamic languages in general means relaxation of most of the things checked by a compiler (syntax is perhaps the only thing checked in advance). This usually means variable existence and even function invocation validity are not verified until necessary. They usually use dynamic typing because static typing goes against the relaxations.

Answer (score 1):

I put this as a comment but it was burried a bit.

def DOES give a type, it uses the type of "Object".  It is as though every variable defined in Java was defined as an object... (so def x=7 in Groovy is exactly the same as Object x=7 in Java, no more or less typed).

These objects ALWAYS cary their type info around in both languages.  These two are also equivilent:

```
Groovy:
def x=5
assert(x == 5)
x="Hey, I changed type!"
assert(x == "Hey, I changed type!")

Java:
Object x=5
assert(x == 5);
x="Hey, I--well I kinda changed my type!"
assert(x.equals("Hey, I--well I kinda changed my type!"))
```

The big difference is that Java enforces (at compile time) that you ONLY call known methods on the type of class it thinks you have.. so on the above example, .toString() and .equals() are really the only useful methods.  To do math you'd have to do something like this:

```
Object x=5;
Object y=7;
Object z=(int)x + (int) y;
assert(z == 12);  
// I believe Integer z will automatically turn 
// to an int here, but this might not compile :)
```

In Groovy the language will simply try to call the method anyway and either succeed or fail at runtime.

This is possible to emulate with Java by using reflection, you could have everything typed "Object" (as it is with groovy's "def") and write a reflective utility to do something like this:

```
Object s="Hey, Wassup???";
Object s2=magic(s, "toLowerCase")
assert(s2.equals("hey, wassup???"));
```

Groovy just hides the "magic".

So I don't think you could say one is inherently more dynamic than the other, although you probably could say that using reflection makes both language dynamic and you could also say that Groovy uses reflection a LOT more than java...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in Java you had to tell it the full type of the variable. 'int' in your example. You could have said 'float' or 'Map' or 'MyClassWithALongName'.

In Groovy you just said 'def' to indicate there was a variable but you told it nothing of the content type.

Comment: That does not answer the question. I know that it could be various typed that you mentioned, but that's not my question.

Comment: @Learner Then you need to clarify your question: you're saying something explicitly not static typing is static typing.

Comment: That does not answer the question. I know that it could be various typed that you mentioned, but that's not my question. The question is, if programmers are enforced to explicitly declare variable type in Groovy (i.e by default def type or String etc), then Groovy should also be considered as statically typed language. Because one can not declare variable as type-less `x = 5; //directly using variable`. Typeless variable declaration is only exceptable in PHP!

Comment: @Learner ... `def` doesn't declare a type. To quote: "def" is a replacement for a type name. In variable definitions it is used to indicate that you don't care about the type. "def" is basically an alias for `Object`. In other words, ANY TYPE. That's dynamic typing.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Correct, if def is an alias for Object, then doesn't this mean that Object is a type on its own?

Comment: @Learner ... I'm not sure why this is complicated. In Java, if you have an `Object` reference, you can call `Object` methods on it. In Groovy, if you have `def x`, you can send whatever message you want to it, and if the object can respond to it, it will. That is the *definition* of dynamic typing. Not sure how else to explain it. Good luck!

Comment: @DaveNewton - I think your confusing yourself with dynamic language? dynamic type and dynamic language are two different concepts.

Comment: @Learner I'm pretty sure I'm not.

Comment: @Learner Another way to put it is that, in Java, the type of a variable is static. Static means it is unchanging. The type of a variable  tells what sorts of data values it can hold. A Java variable can hold only one type of data. In Groovy, the type of a variable is dynamic. Dynamic means it is changable. It won't change without you doing something but the data itself has a type and the variable just holds it, no matter the type. (I'm saying nothing about whether they are dynamic languages. I'm just talking about they type-ing.)